# For each row, find if any previous rows contains a higher value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to solve a Line of Sight (LoS) problem using SQL in PostgreSQL and PostGIS. To do this I have a table `pitch_at_point` that contains an id, a point geometry and a pitch.

`pitch_at_point(id integer,geom geometry,degrees float)`

The id column's lowest value is the starting point for the LoS and the highest is furthest away. For each of these points I want to determine if there are any points with a lower id, which also has a higher pitch (degrees). If this is the case, then the point can't be seen.

I'm stuck trying to find a solution. I have tried using the recursive query as in the SQL below:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
walk_points AS 
(
  SELECT ARRAY[id] AS idlist,geom,degrees,id
  FROM pitch_at_point
  WHERE degrees = (SELECT max(degrees) FROM pitch_at_point)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT array_append(w.idlist, n.id) AS idlist,n.geom,n.degrees,n.id 
  FROM pitch_at_point n, walk_points w
  WHERE n.degrees < any(SELECT n.degrees FROM pitch_at_point WHERE NOT       
  w.idlist @> ARRAY[n.id])
)
SELECT * FROM walk_points
```

I expected to get a return of all points that is preceded by points that have a higher pitch, but I only get a result of a single point, and always the same point even if I use `WHERE n.degrees > any(`.
I have a hard time figuring out the PostgreSQL recursive CTE so if anybody can help me on my way I would appreciate it.

Comment: Note: Postgres needs the `RECURSIVE` keyword for recursive queries.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it could be solved with a window function.

This will give you a true/false flag for records where a previous degrees field (ordered by id) is greater than the degrees for the current row:

```
    case  when degrees < max( degrees ) over( 
            order by id 
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding 
          ) 
          then true 
          else false 
    end as higher_value_present
```

See SQLfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/23196/1

From your question, I wasn't clear on whether there was a set of ids for each geom point that you want to apply this logic to?  If this is the case, you can partition the window function by geom:

```
    case  when degrees < max( degrees ) over( 
            partition by geom
            order by id 
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding 
          ) 
          then true 
          else false 
    end as higher_value_present
```

Comment: Thanks! Hadn't been looking close enough at the window functions. Guess I'll have to learn on that subject.
Haven't tried to partition by geom as each of them represents only on point, so no sets of id's I guess

Comment: Glad it helped! Window functions can be incredibly powerful, and are definitely worth learning about.  I mainly mentioned the partition by clause to show that the window doesn't have to apply across the whole table - it can relate to a subset based on the current value of a column :)

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but isn't this simply:

```
select
  id, geom, degrees
from pitch_at_point
where exists
(
  select *
  from pitch_at_point before
  where before.id < pitch_at_point.id
  and before.degree > pitch_at_point.degree
);
```

This gets all points where a record with a lower ID has a higher pitch.

The same thing may be faster with the windowing version of MAX:

```
select id, geom, degrees
from
(
  select
    id, geom, degrees,
    max(degreees) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) 
      as max_degrees_before
  from pitch_at_point
) data
where degrees < max_degrees_before;
```

Comment: Also a great answer. Really sorry I can't accept both as the one that solved my problem

Comment: Agreed... This is a great answer. Good to see a non window function approach as well.